# Efficiently filtering a large dataset conditionally

Tags: filter, google-cloud-platform, conditional-statements, bigdata

I have large dataset, ~500 million observations. These observations span over many years. Each observation contains a date and an ID that corresponds to the observations location.

I'd like remove all location IDs that aren't contained in the first year of observations. I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to do this.

I'm currently working in Google Cloud Platform. I know I can do this in Pyspark, but that would take forever. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: Incase you tried this in pyspark, plz post the code. So that someone could check if that be optimized to reduce execution time.